# Function returns nothing when trying to return the url of a puppeteer page as a string

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to write a webscraper tool that returns the url of the first result from a search based on some input. Here is the test.js file I'm using to try and test the webscraper:

```
const BrowserTool = async(props, websiteNum) => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(props.websites[websiteNum]);

    await page.setViewport({width: 1080, height: 1024});
    
    let ingredients = "";
    for (var ingredient in props.ingredients) {
        ingredients += '${ingredient} '  ;
    }
    await page.type('#typeaheadinput', '${ingredients}');
    await page.keyboard.press('Enter');
    const searchResultSelector = '#mod-site-search-results-1';
    await page.waitForSelector(searchResultSelector);
    await page.click(searchResultSelector);
    const url = page.url();
    await browser.close();
    return(url);
};

export default BrowserTool;

let object = {ingredients: ["chicken breast"], websites: ["https://www.foodnetwork.com/"]};
let returnString = BrowserTool(object, 0);
console.log(returnString);
```

I originally didn't have the `await page.keyboard.press('Enter');` line and I figured that might be the issue, however there's still nothing printing to the console. I also tried switching `const url = page.url();` with `const url = await page.evaluate(() => document.location.href);` and that also didn't work.

Comment: `return(url);` -> `return url;` ?

Comment: still not getting anything from that either :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few primary issues:

- You're not `await`ing the promise returned by `BrowserTool`.
- `const url = page.url();` happens immediately after `await page.click(searchResultSelector);` without necessarily giving the navigation a chance to resolve. You probably mean to `waitForNavigation` as follows:

  ```js
  await Promise.all([
    page.waitForNavigation(),
    page.click(searchResultSelector),
  ]);
  const url = page.url();
  ```

There are other issues and antipatterns to consider:

- Instead of navigating to a page, typing into an input and pressing a button, it's easier and more reliable to navigate directly to the search results page using the URL.
- Instead of clicking a link, waiting for the page to load, then getting its URL, you can probably grab the URL from the link without clicking it. This assumes no redirects, as appears to be the case here.
- Avoid passing an index into an array into a function--do the indexing in the caller.
- Functions should be `camelCased` actions, not nouns (you can omit `get` from the start of the function, though). Noun functions are for class constructors.
- Avoid vague names like `object` and `returnString`.
- Put `browser.close()` in a `finally` block so it runs even if there's an error.

Here's more or less how I'd approach this:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^19.6.3

const firstRecipeResultURL = async searchTerm => {
  let browser;
  try {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const [page] = await browser.pages();
    const url =
      `https://www.foodnetwork.com/search/${searchTerm.replace(/\s/g, "-")}-`;
    await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
    const sel = ".o-RecipeResult .m-MediaBlock__a-Headline a";
    const el = await page.waitForSelector(sel);
    return await el.evaluate(el => el.getAttribute("href"));
  }
  finally {
    browser?.close();
  }
};

firstRecipeResultURL("chicken breast")
  .then(url => console.log(url))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Making a browser is expensive, so depending on your needs, you might want to create and cache a single instance for the duration of your app.